# Move to another Html.EditorFor but first check first letter

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I do to check that the first letter that a Html.EditorFor have is "P" and if it's, focus to the next Html.EditorFor? For example: I have 3 Html.EditorFor I want to do something like my first Html.EditFor has to have "P" for the first letter and if it have it change to the next Html.EditorFor, and with the second i will check "Q" and if it have it to the next Html.EditorFor, and like that ...?

Comment: You need javascript to respond to client side events. (and I assume you mean `EditorFor`)

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it, if someone more need it.

```
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeypress="myFunction(event)">
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1">

function myFunction(e) {
if(e.keyCode === 13)
{
var value = document.getElementById("txt").value;
var txt = value.substr(0,1);

if (txt === "P") {
$(document.getElementById("txt")).css("background-color", "white");
 document.getElementById("txt1").focus();
}else{
 $(document.getElementById("txt")).css("background-color", "red");
 $(document.getElementById("txt")).val("");
}
```

}